# How to download an attachment of recent mail from gmail to specific path?

Tags: java, email, gmail, jakarta-mail

I want to search for specific subject mail from Inbox of gmail and read the content body content and download the .csv attachment of it to the specific path. Later on I want to compare it with another .csv file.

NOTE: I don't want to read all Inbox mail.

Comment: Please include what have you attempted so far and what is the issue you are facing.

Comment: do you already have an email client ? or do you want to implement this in java as well ? maybe you only want to iterate over the already downloaded mails.

Comment: I want iterate over the inbox of Gmail for the verification of the email sent from my application. I am facing problem to identify the recent mail having the attachment in it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Folder.search](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#search-javax.mail.search.SearchTerm-) method with a [SubjectTerm](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/search/SubjectTerm.html) can be used to find messages matching a subject string.  You'll find an example in the [search.java](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/search.java) sample program.

You'll need to understand how to examine the parts of the message to find the correct attachment.  The [msgshow.java](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/msgshow.java) sample program might be helpful.

If that's not enough to get you started, update your question with the code you've tried and the specific questions you have.